# Select an element but not its child element using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, dom, jquery-selectors

I am trying to change few things in all `<p>` elements inside a DIV, but I don't want the `<a>` tags or any other elements nested inside the `<p>` element to be selected. Is this doable?

```
<div .main-div>
   <p> Select this sentence.......
      <a> Don't select this </a>
   </p>
   <p> Select this too....
      <a> Don't select this </a>
   </p>
</div>
```

I tried the following but did not work:

1. `var bodytext = $( '.main-div p').not('p > a') ; //this selects the <a> tag as well`
2. `var bodytext = $( '.site-inner p:visible').not('p:has(a)') ;`
   //this does not select both the

   because both of them have  tag.

I would really appreciate if anyone could advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not explain what you're actually after? Also... `<div .main-div>` what's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access text nodes directly with jQuery. You can however access the nodes of the underlying element the jQuery object contains

```js
$('.main-div p').each(function(i){
   const firstSentence = this.childNodes[0];
   firstSentence.textContent = 'Change #' +(i+1)  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-div">
   <p> Select this sentence.......
      <a> Don't select this </a>
   </p>
   <p> Select this too....
      <a> Don't select this </a>
   </p>
</div>
```